# Using python, how do I delete all text in a text block, without using cut?

Tags: python, scripting, text-editor

I need to delete(or replace) all text, but without using Cut, because it copies the text to the clipboard. How do I do this?

Comment: So you can select all the text in the text editor window in Blender and Cut works but copies everything to the clipboard? Why can you not just hit the Del/Delete/Backspace key on the keyboard? which version of Blender?

Comment: I need to do it with python.

Comment: sorry, still confused. Can you update your question with your current code. Any dealings I have had with text in Python has just been as a string and then just used basic string manipulation. How does the text block you are dealing with differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Text blocks](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/bpy.types.Text.html) have a `clear()` method which will clear all lines:

```
import bpy
bpy.data.texts['Text Block Name'].clear()
```

Alternatively, if you need to access each line individually, Text blocks have a `lines` property which you can loop over, setting the `body` property of each line to a blank string (`""`):

```
import bpy
t = bpy.data.texts['Text Block Name']

for line in t.lines:
    line.body = ""
```

Comment: you can also t.clear()

Comment: @lemon Yep, just realised that. Thanks.